# Wordpress on Ubuntu Server behind Synology Reverse Proxy (HTTP-HTTS) settings

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, wordpress, mariadb, synology

I am currently setting up my website and need some help while setting the access as it should be.

Here the facts:

- I have a static and public IPv4 address
- registered TLD (gear-trade.at)
- DNS entry pointing to my public IP
- Ubuntu Server running NGNIX and MariaDB with Wordpress running
- Router is forwarding Port 80/443 to my SynologyNas as there are multiple Virtual Hosts with other websites running
- Reverse Proxy on Synology is forwarding https://www.gear-trade.at to http://:80
- Synology has the  SSL Cert and serves it for the reverse proxy

The first question is: Do I need to create a reverse proxy entry for every type of domain that I want to be forwarded? Because I want that my website is reachable with www and without.

My other missing setting is the configuration on the Nginx part. Currently, the server is listening on Port 80 without any HTTPS redirect.

[image]

So basically what I need to get:

Call my website from the Internet with www or without and be able to use only HTTPS. The certificate should be still served from synology nas which has the reverse proxy.

In the Wordpress settings currently the Website URL is http://www.gear-trade.at

Hope someone gets my issue and can support me with it.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide us with what you did to resolve this?